# how to change class of a label when input field is checked in angularjs?

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to change the default class from `fa-circle-o` to `fa-dot-circle-o` when the input radio button is checked.

```
<label ng-repeat="pair in exchange.fiat" class="fa fa-circle-o" ng-class="{ fa-dot-circle-o: currency === pair }">
    <input type="radio" name="currency" value="{{pair}}" ng-model="$parent.currency"> {{pair}}
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `ngClass`, if the CSS class name is dash-separated, wrap it inside quotes:

```
<label ng-repeat="pair in exchange.fiat" class="fa fa-circle-o" 
ng-class="{ 'fa-dot-circle-o': currency === pair }">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the ng-class... just fire a function to get the class... Something like this:

```
<label ng-repeat="pair in exchange.fiat" class="fa {{getClass()}}">
    <input type="radio" name="currency" value="{{pair}}" ng-model="$parent.currency"> {{pair}}
</label>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.getClass = function() {
    var out = "fa-circle-o";

    if ($scope.currency === $scope.pair) {
        out = "fa-dot-circle-o";
    }

    return out;
};
```

EDIT: just reread the question... updated code above.